# How to get symetrical matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix

**I have to write function:**

**void function (int * a [], int sq) checking if the sq-degree square matrix is ​​symmetrical 
(relative to the main diagonal upper left - lower right) and performing any transposition of this matrix.**

**My main** :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void  function(int* a[], int sq);
int main() {
const int sq = 10;
int a[sq][sq];

int *tab[sq];
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    tab[i] = a[i];
}

function(tab,sq);
return 0;
}
```

**My function**:

```
void  function(int* a[], int sq) {
cout << "tell me the number and i give you (sq x sq) matrix:";
cin >> sq;

for(int i = 0; i < sq; i ++) {
    for(int j = 0 ; j < sq; j++) {
        cin >> a[i][j];
    }
}
// 3 7 8 2
// 7 4 5 5
// 8 2 1 6
// 2 5 6 1

cout << "Matrix is " << sq << " degree:" << endl;

for(int i = 0; i< sq; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < sq; j++) {
        if(a[0][j] == a[i][0] && a[i-1][j] == a[i][j-1] ) {
            cout << a[i][j] << " "; //  if symetrical
        }  else {
            cout << a[j][i] << " "; //if not, lets do transposition
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    }

    }
```

**Example**:

```
// 3 7 8 2
// 7 4 5 5
// 8 2 1 6
// 2 5 6 1
```

This is symetrical and should give me **output**:

Matrix is 4 degree:

```
3 7 8 2
7 4 5 5
8 2 1 6
2 5 6 1
```

But it's  doing transposition and give me:

Matrix is 4 degree:

```
3 7 8 2
7 4 2 5
8 5 1 6
2 5 6 1
```

If i understand contents of exercise...

Comment: The example code uses a 10x10 matrix. The example data is a 4x4. Please provide a [mcve] and replace all user input by hardcoded values. Did you try to step line by line through your code with a debugger?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on matrices, but i'm pretty sure that matrix isn't symmetrical because of elements [2,3] and [3,2]

Comment: okey, atleast now i see..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace the for loop like below

your code :

```
for(int i = 0; i< sq; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < sq; j++) {
        if(a[0][j] == a[i][0] && a[i-1][j] == a[i][j-1] ) {
            cout << a[i][j] << " "; //  if symetrical
        }  else {
            cout << a[j][i] << " "; //if not, lets do transposition
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    }
```

Replace with below code :

```
for(int i = 0; i< sq; i++) {
    for(int j = i; j < sq; j++) {


        if(a[i][j] == a[j][i] ) {
            cout << a[i][j] << " "; //  if symetrical
        }  else {
            cout << a[j][i] << " "; //if not, lets do transposition
        }


    }
    cout << endl;
    }
```